# jquery select each "row" of floated childs

Tags: jquery, html, css, each, slice

So I have multiple elements which are actually in flex parent, but it looks like they are floated, but they are centered at the same time (max. 3 children per row) but when you resize parent they create new row obviously.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  max-width: 950px;
  overflow:auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 8.3px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Or here in jsfiddle which I created http://jsfiddle.net/6qdp3sxa/4/.

And I need to select each row in jquery.
For example when there are 3 children in row, it can be something like this:

```
$('.parent .child').slice(0, 3).each(function() {});
$('.parent .child').slice(4, 7).each(function() {});
```

But in some kind of loop.
I have no idea how to do it, can you help me?

**EDIT:** These children are there dynamically so I cant do those slices by myself, because someone can add them or remove them.

Comment: I can't think of a practical way of doing this with a `flexbox`. The entire idea behind flexbox is that it sort of dynamically adjusts based on the needs. However I could think of a way to solve this, if you were willing to switch to a `grid` layout which can have its rows defined

Comment: I used flexbox just because of centering those children.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve by grouping them as rows?

Comment: That's actually hard to explain, it's cause of effect when you scroll to each row, I'll try to update that jsfiddle so you can see that effect.

Comment: @DavidThomas http://jsfiddle.net/6qdp3sxa/13/

Comment: Try and take the time, if you can, although I can appreciate the difficulty of explaining the problem. But if we solve the right problem we're likely to help you more than if we solve the wrong problem... :)

Comment: Oh, you answered after I answered, nevermind I commented that jsfiddle :)

Comment: But as you can see in that js fiddle it triggers every child with that effect when you scroll to the start of parent, but I want to trigger only one row when you scroll to it and then next row only when you scroll to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me put some plot here, you may have clue to write code.
Use `screen.width` to check browser width break points for 1 per row, 2 per row, or 3 per row. Then put your slice statement under each condition.

below is example for 3 per row, enjoy :)

```
const count=3;
const selectRow=row=>$('.parent .child').slice(row*count, row*count+count);
const row=Math.ceil($('.parent .child').length/count);


for(let i=0;i<row;i++) selectRow(i).html(i);

for(let i=0;i<row;i++) selectRow(i).each((i,v)=>{//i is the index for each div in the row })
```

Just keep in mind that my row start with 0

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qdp3sxa/25/)

Comment: Oh my bad, I forgot to say that these children are there dynamically, so someone can add them or remove them any time.

Comment: Even they are dynamic, you can regain all of them by using $(".parent .child")

Comment: Maybe we don't understand each other, when I would write these silces by myself I would have to write from 0,3 to 96, 100 and I don't want to do that.

Comment: Even when they are like 50 children?

Comment: Yes, I can use loop

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking for. As you can see at the end of my question: "But in some kind of loop..."

Comment: Give me a moment

Comment: No problem. I cross my fingers for you :)

Comment: So I achieved my goal with your answer as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/6qdp3sxa/26/, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, I know what you actually want through talking, good job.

Comment: I appreciate that. Thank you and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've got something to exactly know on which "row" is a particular div.

This is a good start for you if it isn't exactly what you are looking for.

The trick is achived by looping the divs and comparing their top offset.

```js
console.clear();

var targets = $(".parent .child");

$(window).on("load resize",function(){
  // Get the first offset to start a comparison
  var divOffset = targets.first().offset().top;

  // Loop throught each .child to add a row is not the same offset.
  var rows = 0;
  var div_per_row = [];
  targets.each(function(){
    if($(this).offset().top != divOffset){
      divOffset = $(this).offset().top;
      rows++;
    }
    div_per_row[rows] = div_per_row[rows]+1 || 1;
  });

  // Now you have a exact div per row count in an array.
  console.log(div_per_row)

  // Making fun with it. You could do whatever from this point.
  var count = 0;
  for(i=0;i<div_per_row.length;i++){
    for(k=0;k<div_per_row[i];k++){

      var rowNum = i+1;
      targets.eq(count).text("I'm on row#"+rowNum);
      console.log(i);
      count++;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  max-width: 950px;
  overflow:auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 8.3px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Since it's not easy to resize a snippet, here is a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/eLdYjd?editors=1111).

Comment: This looks promising, but how do I use each function for each child on that row? Do you have any idea?

Comment: In my "fun" part... You can give it an additional class, or a data-* attribute. Then use that for further selection.

Comment: It depends a lot on what you want to do... But look [**here**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/OoRPOV?editors=1111) with a class added.

Comment: mmm Cool... I just updated the second codepen for a slight glitch... And it seems like you accepted the other answer. ;)

Comment: Your answer is pretty robust, but to be honest I don't know how to achieve my goal with this solution. I feel bad for you, I guess you spent some time coding this and making codepens, but anyway I will save it for future projects and thank you very much for your time :) Greetings SenTisso

Comment: I bet it will become handy one day. Thank you very much for your help @LouysPatriceBessette.

Comment: Okay, No problem. If that is to be useful someday, I'm happy! :)